# How to have a secondary y axis in a nested GridSpec?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to obtain this figure:
[image]
But with two plots inside each graph, like this:
[image]
Here is a sample of the code I used for the first figure

```
measures = ['ACE', 'SCE', 'LZs', 'LZc']
conditions = ['dark','light','flick3','flick10','switch']
    outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
for measure in measures:
    inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(5, 1, subplot_spec=outer_grid[measures.index(measure)])
    ax={}
    for cond in conditions:
        c=conditions.index(cond)
        ax[c] = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid[c])
        if c != 0:
            ax[c].get_shared_y_axes().join(ax[0], ax[c])
        ax[c].plot()
        ax[c+n]=ax[c].twinx()
        ax[c+n].scatter()
        ax[c+n].set_ylim(0,5)
        fig.add_subplot(ax[c],ax[c+n])
```

For the second plot, it's basically the same without the first loop and GridSpec, using `ax[c]=plt.subplot('51{c}')` instead of `ax[c]=plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid[c])`.

As you can see, when using GridSpec I still have the secondary y axis but not the scatter plot associated.

I guess the short question would be **How to write `fig.add_subplot(ax[c],ax[c+n])` properly?**

(`fig.add_subplot(ax[c])` `fig.add_subplot(ax[c+n])` in two lines doesn't work.)

Comment: To put it differently, I need that kind of figure [A Nested GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#a-complex-nested-gridspec-using-subplotspec) with a second curve on a secondary y axis in each graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from your question exactly which data you're plotting in each subplot, plus the way you're creating your subplots seems a little convoluted, which is probably why you're having problems. Here is how I would do it:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs
measures = ['ACE', 'SCE', 'LZs', 'LZc']
conditions = ['dark','light','flick3','flick10','switch']
colors = ['g','c','b','r','grey']
Npoints = 10
data = [np.random.random((Npoints,len(measures))) for i in range(len(conditions))]
gs00 = gs.GridSpec(len(conditions), 1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

for i,condition in enumerate(conditions):
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs00[i])
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax1.plot(range(Npoints), data[i][:,0], 'o-', color=colors[i], label=measures[0])
    ax2.plot(range(Npoints), data[i][:,1], 'o-.', color=colors[i], label=measures[1])

    ax1.set_ylim((-0.1,1.1))
    ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())

    ax1.set_title(condition)
```

[image]

**EDIT** to get the same thing repeated 4 times, the logic is exactly the same, you just have to play around with the gridspec. But the only things that matters are the lines `ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[j])` followed by `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`, which will create a second axis on top of the first

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs
measures = ['ACE', 'SCE', 'LZs', 'LZc']
conditions = ['dark','light','flick3','flick10','switch']
colors = ['g','c','b','r','grey']
Npoints = 10
data = [np.random.random((Npoints,len(measures))) for i in range(len(conditions))]
gs00 = gs.GridSpec(2,2)

plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

grid_x, grid_y = np.unravel_index(range(len(measures)),(2,2))

for i,measure in enumerate(measures):
    gs01 = gs.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(len(conditions), 1, subplot_spec=gs00[grid_x[i],grid_y[i]])
    for j,condition in enumerate(conditions):
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs01[j])
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        ax1.plot(range(Npoints), data[j][:,0], 'o-', color=colors[j], label=measures[0])
        ax2.plot(range(Npoints), data[j][:,1], 'o-.', color=colors[j], label=measures[1])

        ax1.set_ylim((-0.1,1.1))
        ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())

        if j==0:
            ax1.set_title(measure)
```

[image]

Comment: This is basically my second plot, what I need is to have that four times in the figure.